# Dynamically add columns to dataframe via apply

Tags: python, pandas

The following code applies a function `f` to a dataframe column `data_df["c"]` and concats the results to the original dataframe, i.e. concatenating 1024 columns to the dataframe `data_df`.

```
data_df = apply_and_concat(data_df, "c", lambda x: f(x, y), [y + "-dim" + str(i) for i in range(0,1024)])

def apply_and_concat(df, field, func, column_names):
    return pd.concat((
        df,
        df[field].apply(
            lambda cell: pd.Series(func(cell), index=column_names))), axis=1)
```

The problem is that I want to execute this dynamically, meaning that I don't know how many columns it returns. `f`returns a list. Is there any better or easier way to add these columns without the need to specify the number of columns before?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `pd.concat(df, df.apply(...), axis=1)` already solves the main task well. It seems like your main question really boils down to "how do I name an unknown number of columns", where you're happy to use a name based on sequential integers. For that, use `itertools.count()`:

```
import itertools

f_modified = lambda x: dict(zip(
    ('{}-dim{}'.format(y, i) for i in itertools.count()),
    f(x, y)
))
```

Then use `f_modified` instead of `f`. That way, you get a dictionary instead of a list, with an arbitrary number of dynamically generated names as keys. When converting this dictionary to a Series, you'll end up with the keys being used as the index, so you don't need to provide an explicit list as the index, and hence don't need to know the number of columns in advance.

Comment: That's what the code already does. But what about the column names?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas My apologies, I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. Does the new answer better resolve your question?